# Correctly building local python3, with bz2 support

Tags: python, python-3.x, bzip2, ldflags, cflags

I am trying to build a local version of python3 (specifically python3.7, but same issue with 3.6.6), but am running into problems with linking to some C libraries and/or headers (at least that is what I think the problem is).

I am able to build python3.7, but run into problems with bzip2 (but I suspect there will be other system libraries that I am missing an not aware of). This manifests itself when trying to import various packages/modules that require it as an import error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

From this stackoverflow question - [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806122/missing-python-bz2-module) - it appears that I have built python without the right bz2 headers. The python build itself does not fail.

The specific question is how to build a local version of python with bz2? More generally, the question is how to properly link to system libraries? (since there may be others I have not encountered errors with)

In terms of what I have tried - I found this (oldish) question - 
[How do you assign bz2 to an altinstall of python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915137/how-do-you-assign-bz2-to-an-altinstall-of-python/13957258) and this more recent question [Compiling bz2 support in python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384018/compiling-bz2-support-in-python2) and tried a few things based off these.

First problem  I ran into is actually finding the right libraries etc to link (the solution in the above question suggests to set `CFLAGS="-I/path/to/bz2/include"` and `LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/bz2/lib"`). Presumably these are on my system somewhere (ubuntu 16.04), since the system installs of python2.7 and python3.5 have no issues with bzip2.

I found `libbz2.so.1` (and some others in) `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` - but the folders didn't seem to follow the pattern of the example/answer above.  As such, I built a new local version of bz2 (in `.bzp` in my local folder) and then tried linking to that when I tried to build python3.7, using the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/.localpython CFLAGS="-I/home/user/.bz2/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/user/.bz2/lib"
```

I also tried a more generic configuration (which was loosely based off [Compile Python with bz2 support](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3504#issuecomment-32755856), linked to in the second article above.)

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/.python CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

(both of which were unsuccessful)

Any pointers, tips etc greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be great to see the actual output from the failed commands. This could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: The build doesn't actually fail - it just doesn't build with bz2 support (which shows up if you try and import various modules that use it)..Will edit question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu does not, by default, install the files needed to include bz2 support (or any other such library support) when compiling Python. You need to add the *development headers* package for the library.

For `bz2` support on Ubuntu, that's the [`libbz2-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libbz2-dev). You'll need to install more such packages for other features.

The package puts the headers in a standard location, one the Python `configure` script knows to find. You do not need additional flags.

Extrapolating from the [Python 3.6 build dependencies on Ubuntu 17.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/artful/python3.6), you'd also want:

```
libbluetooth-dev
libbz2-dev
libdb-dev
libexpat1-dev
libffi-dev
libgdbm-dev
liblzma-dev
libmpdec-dev
libncursesw5-dev
libreadline-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libssl-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

and if you want to support the Tk GUI library, `tk-dev` and `blt-dev`.

Comment: Thanks - that solved the initial problem (...and perhaps future problems). I don't suppose you can shed any light on why bz2 works on the system install (i.e. `import bz2` works fine on the system python3?

Comment: @djmac: because the system Python was compiled with those headers present.